# Managing blocked users in ASP.NET Core 2.1 API which uses JWT

Tags: authentication, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-2.1

I have been using JWT to authenticate the users for the HTTP endpoints in my ASP.NET Core 2.1 API project. I have configured the authentication service and everything is going on well.

while generating the token, I usually set the expiry to 24 hours. My problem is, what if the user is blocked by the admin after issuing the token. Now that the token is issued the authentication middleware will simply authenticate the request.

So, I thought I need to intercept every request to make a backend call to know whether the user is blocked or not. I can do this at every endpoint level, but it is not so efficient I think.

What are the optimal solutions for this issue, which is quite common? Are there better ways to solve it than what I thought?

Answer (score 1):

When you choose to use a JWT then accept the nature of the JWT. This means that the only way to have 'real-time' information is to expire the token when the information becomes obsolete. Set the lifetime of the access token to a small window, like less than five minutes. This way you know the information is always valid and you don't have to change anything about the current handling. This is 'almost real-time', as the changes become effective within five minutes.

The advantage of a short lifetime is that this also increases the security of your website. When the token is compromised, it can only be used for a short time.

You'll have to add support for a refresh token, because you don't want the user to login every five minutes. So when the access token expires use a refresh token to request a new access token. This will only work for apps that can keep a secret. Because the refresh token is very powerful and you don't want it to fall into the wrong hands. You can use one-time only refresh tokens to limit the risks and add strategies to detect different behaviour. For more details read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52850880/how-the-server-verifies-the-jwt-client/52864895#52864895).

You can also choose to remove authorization claims from the JWT and move authorization to your middleware, where you can real-time check the permissions of the user. In that case the JWT only includes the user claims that identify and model the user. Claims that are not likely to change very often. As a result the access token doesn't have to be short-lived, but for security reasons I think this is still advisable.

The minimal requirement is a `sub` or `userid` claim. This is enough to identify the user and grant the user access to the website.

I think the [Policy Server](https://policyserver.io/) is a good example of a possible middleware authorization implementation. Here the middleware reads permissions from a json file and adds permissions as claims to the identity. Where policies decide what the user is allowed to do. Also implement [resource-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x).

An alternative is to use [reference tokens](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/reference_tokens.html), as implemented by IdentityServer. IdentityServer stores the contents of the token in a data store and will only issue a unique identifier for this token back to the client. The API receiving this reference must then open a back-channel communication to IdentityServer to validate the token.

The advantage here is that you can revoke the reference token at any time, using the revocation endpoint.